# use of sendResourceAtURL gives "Unsupported resource type"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5, multipeer-connectivity

I am trying to send an image that I pick via imagePickerController using **sendResourceAtURL**.
I get the URL in method **didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo** as

```
NSURL *refURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
```

But when I call

```
[self.mySession sendResourceAtURL:refURL withName:@"test" toPeer:peerid withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error){
                if (error)....
```

I get always the unsupported resource type error.
I believe the construction of the url is not correct and I need sth else.
When I create an url with a local file in my bundle, then it gets transmitted fine.
Any ideas?

Thanks,
Zois

Comment: Have you confirmed that `refURL` is in fact an `NSURL` object that points to a valid resource?

Comment: Well yes, its an image picked by the image picker browser. If I log it I get _assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=EE8FE14C-63FF-4D8B-BB12-3E97506C2188&ext=PNG_ . So as I mention I have to construct the url to that object somewhat differently. Eg by using the ALAssetsLibrary I can get to the image's name for instance.

Comment: Can you paste the entire method where you assign the URL to your `refURL` variable?

Answer (score 4):

I used the code provided in the Multipeer Group Chat example app and that worked.  You first have to write the file to your documents directory and then send that url.

```
// Don't block the UI when writing the image to documents
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    // We only handle a still image
    UIImage *imageToSave = (UIImage *)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    // Save the new image to the documents directory
    NSData *pngData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToSave, 1.0);

    // Create a unique file name
    NSDateFormatter *inFormat = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [inFormat setDateFormat:@"yyMMdd-HHmmss"];
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image-%@.JPG", [inFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
    // Create a file path to our documents directory
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
    [pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; // Write the file
    // Get a URL for this file resource
    NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

    MCPeerID *peer = self.session.connectedPeers[0];
    [self.session sendResourceAtURL:imageUrl withName:imageName toPeer:peer withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to send picture to %@, %@", peer.displayName, error.localizedDescription);
            return;
        }
        NSLog(@"Sent picture to %@", peer.displayName);
        //Clean up the temp file
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        [fileManager removeItemAtURL:imageUrl error:nil];
    }];
});
```

Comment: Is there a list available where we can see all the supported resource types? I tried sending a PNG file and I got the Unsupported Resource Type error.

Comment: Not sure.  file:// was the one that worked for me.  Images that you get from the photo library have a different type. http:// may work as well.

Comment: Yep, got it working. My mistake!! In fact we can transfer any type of resource. You can create your custom file extension as well.

Comment: Mmm, im missing something?, not found the solution, someone can tell me which was the solution to this problem?, please.

Comment: @GonzaloBahamondez did you try the code in my answer?

Comment: My resource is a MP3 file, not a image. i should use the same way? or i need ask this in a new question?

Comment: This is the solution.  Even though sendResourceAtURL takes a URL as the source, an AssetsLibrary URL is not a supported URL.  You need to open the image/video from the AssetsLibrary and save it to your local folder and then construct a URL to the temporary file and send that.  It would be very convenient if you could send directly from the picker's returned URL.